# Elsa-workflows Redirect Http action behavior

Tags: elsa-workflows

What will be the behavior of a workflow after a Http Redirect Activity execution?
In the designer the http redirect activity shows a 'Done' output but when we look at the source code I couldn't realize how it will return a 'Done' output instead, it just redirects the response to the informed url. By the way, the next activity, right after a http redirect activity, is neither executed or put in suspended mode. Maybe I'm missing something here and didn't put the pieces together right the way.
Can someone please help me to fit those pieces together? By code example or pointing me a helpful topic from Elsa-workflows docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you identified a bug with the **Redirect** activity. The bug being that even though it exposes the `"Done"` outcome, the activity doesn't actually return said outcome, as you observed correctly.

I just [pushed a fix](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/commit/87c7cb08eccf5e6d46f2fbe20a57e48c2f7e0460).

Thanks for the question!